# MySQL 5.7: UNIQUE and exists

Tags: mysql, laravel, unique, primary-key, exists

I have 3 tables: usuaris, versions and usuari_versio for the relationship:

```
id | usuari_id | versio_id | updated_at | created_at
```

The following query, generated by laravel, is returning the user only if the first row of the relationship has versio_id = 2 when email has UNIQUE constraint.

However, if I remove the UNIQUE constraint the query is returning the user for any versio_id in relationship (as desired).

I have also seen that if instead of using email I use `usuaris`.`id`, which is PK, the same result with email with UNIQUE constraint is happening.

```
select * 
from `usuaris`
where 
    `usuaris`.`email` = 'mail@mail.com'
    and exists (
        select * 
        from `versions` 
        inner join `usuari_versio` on `versions`.`id` = `usuari_versio`.`versio_id` 
        where 
            `usuari_versio`.`usuari_id` = `usuaris`.`id` 
            and `versions`.`id` = 2
    ) 
limit 1
```

I don't really understand why is happening this. But I need to get the user when the subquery is returning true and also when email (or id) is matching.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the "=" of the subquery for a "like" (without %) and now is working as I expected:

```
...
and `versions`.`id` LIKE 2
...
```

It is also working if I change the "=" for a "like" of email comparison.

Why is happening that?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from usuaris usu
where 
usuaris.email = 'mail@mail.com' and
EXISTS (
 select ver.id from versions ver inner join usuari_versio usuver
 on ver.id = usuver.versio_id 
 where usuver.usuari_id = usu.id 
 and ver.id = 2
) 
limit 1;
```

It says that you are selecting one user where the email is only 'mail@mail.com', and if usuari_versio have version 2 in versio_id with usuari_id in usuari_versio. it can return if there is just one Email 'mail@mail.com'. But if you have more than one 'mail@mail.com' (not unique) it gonna be probably wrong. The Limit 1 says it going to select the first user where has that email.

```
select * 
from usuaris usu
where 
usuaris.email = 'mail@mail.com
```

can return more than one row if email is not unique or primery key.

Maybe a good way to select it can be like this (If email is unique)

```
select * 
from usuaris usu inner join usuari_versio usuver
on usuver.usuari_id = usu.id
inner join versions ver 
on usuver.versio_id = ver.id
where 
usu.email = 'mail@mail.com' and
ver.id = 2
LIMIT 1;
```

if not try searching with the usuaris pk

```
select * 
    from usuaris usu inner join usuari_versio usuver
    on usuver.usuari_id = usu.id
    inner join versions ver 
    on usuver.versio_id = ver.id
    where 
    usu.email = 'mail@mail.com' and
    ver.id = 2 and
    usu.id = USUARISPK;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using Laravel framework and I cannot easily change the query.